# Why is enumerate label centre aligned?

Tags: enumerate, alignment

newbie here. I'm trying to get the (a) to be aligned on the left in line with (b) I've been googling for about an hour now and haven't found a way around it yet...any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[(a)] 
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\large{Text}}\\
            More text\\
        \end{center}
    \item[(b)]
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: `\item` labels are actually right aligned (not center aligned).  I know there are some questions on the site to address this.  But basically, you need the label to be something like `\item[\makebox[<dimension>][l]{a}]...`, where `<dimension>` is an appropriate length.  The key is finding the way to automate that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried inserting a "filler piece", e.g., `\strut`, immediately after `\item[(a)]`?

Comment: note that using enumerate and then manually enumerating the items as `[{a)]`.. negates much of the point of the environment, also `\large` does not take an argument, it should be `\large text` not `\large{text}`

Comment: Thanks, have tried these but it is shifting the text onto a new line. \hspace is doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to obtain with `enumitem`. Also  perhaps yoiu want the centred text to begin on the same line as the item label?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a), align = left]
    \item \leavevmode\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep + \parsep}%
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\large{Text}}\\
            More text\\
        \end{center}
\setcounter{enumi}{12}
    \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can force the label to take the full line rather than adding code within the list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[
align=left,
label={\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-\labelsep][l]{(\alph*)}}]
    \item
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\large Text}\\
            More text\\
        \end{center}
    \item
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

the setting here done in the optional argument to this list but if all your lists are of this form you can set the global settings to use this style, and further simplify the in-document markup.

Comment: That's great thanks. Is there anyway to have it so the text is in line with the item label?

Comment: @CraigMacDonald that would be the default (without the makebox part) I forced the item label full width as you have the center environment (which is adding vertical space, do you really want the text to be centred in the list body but the label overprinted into the left space? anything is possible but...

Comment: @CraigMacDonald specifically things would act more naturally if your enumerate had `\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label=(\alph*)]`  and the item was `\item \textbf{\large Text} \begin{center} more text\end{center}` as then the item label is naturally aligned with the text.

Comment: Thanks for your help David, I had no idea about half these things, now to go through my document and make a load of changes :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item[(a)] \strut% need a little invisble thing here
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\large{Text}}\\
            More text\\
        \end{center}
    \item[(b)]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```